# Avoid SSL Certificate for HTTPCLIENT while making https request in android

Tags: android, android-networking, androidhttpclient

I am using SSL Socket Factory class to make HTTPS request in Android. Is there any way to avoid SSL process in HTTPCLIENT request? Here is my SSL class

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.
If, as it sounds, you are asking if you can make an HTTPS call without using SSL, well, then...no. The 'S' at the end of HTTPS indicates use of SSL. If it's something else, please explain.

Comment: yes when I make https request I need to use the class above. but I dont want my app go thru this everytime I make any https request. for instance; in HTTPURL Connection in android, you can avoid ssl process in there when making any https request. I am just trying to avoid using SSL in HttpClient

Comment: My suggestion is to use a higher-level library (there are several) instead of HttpClient. You shouldn't have to muck around in low-level stuff like SSLContext (unless you really want to).

Comment: what do you mean by higher-level? could you please share me those several?

Comment: Retrofit, Volley, OkHttp

Comment: what is the difference between these and HttpURL ?

Comment: Android Documentation recommend HttpURL  that is the reason I want to using it. but I am using Apache for only Oauth requests so either I need to switch it to HttpUrl or try to find a way to avoid SSL in HTTClient apache.However I am trying to way to avoid SSL first while I already implemented everything there